# Using "Script Table As CREATE To ..." option in SQL Server 2008 R2 SSMS

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I have come up against a very strange problem when using the 'Script Table As CREATE To' option using SQL Server 2008 R2 SSMS.

In my original Northwind database I have this check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  WITH NOCHECK 

   ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Birthdate] 
        CHECK  (([BirthDate] < getdate()))
GO
```

Now, when I run this against a Northwind_Test database I get this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]  
      WITH NOCHECK 
        ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Birthdate] 
             CHECK  (([BirthDate]<getdate()))
GO
```

The difference is the spacing has been removed from the CHECK text.

I need the spacing to remain intact when running scripts from within SSMS.  Is there any SET statement I can use to preserve this spacing and any other formatting?  The reason for this is I am writing a database compare utility and need the formatting to remain intact otherwise the utility will keep saying the database schema is different.

Comment: Perhaps make sure your utility can handle such differences in formatting (either utilizing a SQL Parser or have an internal canonical representation).

Comment: I did think about doing that, but the problem is that SSMS seems to override the formatting.  I am wondering why the Northwind db has the formatting preserved, but not the Northwind_Test db.  Maybe there is a setting in SSMS to turn off this formatting?

Comment: What you want isn't possible.

SQL Server just stores the definition of the check constraint separately (See `definition` column in `sys.check_constraints`) not the original text used to `create` it. Not sure why scripting from one database would include an extra line break.

Comment: The `definition` column in `sys.check_constraints` contains `([BirthDate] < getdate())` which is exactly what I expected.  I was wondering why SQL Server removes the spaces before and after the `<` sign when running the T-SQL query in SSMS.  FYI I am using SMO to extract the database schema.